# Can one say that $\int_{r_{a}}^{r_{b}} \mathrm{d}\vec{r}$ is the infinite sum of infinitesimal magnitudes, $\mathrm{d}r$, with direction, $\hat{r}$?

Tags: integration, vectors, vector-analysis, riemann-integration, vector-fields

Say, for example, that you had a situation where you needed to some up an infinite number of infinitesimally small portions of some vector, $\vec{r}$. This vector, $\vec{r}$, can be then defined as

\begin{equation}
\vec{r} = \int_{r_{a}}^{r_{b}} \mathrm{d}\vec{r}
\end{equation}

which states that the infinite summation of these infinitesimally small vector contributions, $\mathrm{d}r$, will total to the vector, $\vec{r}$.

We can say that this vector, $\vec{r}$, can be split into its components of some direction, $\hat{r}$, and magnitude, $r$, given by the following relation

\begin{equation}
\hat{r} = \dfrac{\vec{r}}{r}
\end{equation}

Using this, we could say that the vector, $\vec{r}$, can be expressed by the following
\begin{equation}
\vec{r} = r\hat{r}
\end{equation}

From the integral which was stated above, we know that, $\vec{r}$, can be expressed as the infinite sum of the infinitesimally small vector contributions, $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$, so perhaps we can express this differential as

\begin{equation} 
\mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \hat{r}\mathrm{d}r
\end{equation}

If this is true, then I could rewrite the previous integral as

\begin{equation}
\vec{r} = \int_{r_{a}}^{r_{b}} \hat{r}\mathrm{d}r
\end{equation}

This makes more sense to me geometrically. I can picture this as going along some function interval which describes the direction of the vector at any point, and providing it with a magnitude at that direction. Summing up all these magnitudes pointing in some, $\hat{r}$, direction should, in turn, provide me with the total vector, $\vec{r}$.

Comment: I have realized that writing it in terms of $\hat{r}\mathrm{d}r$ only makes sense if all portions of $\mathrm{d}r$ are pointing in the direction of $\vec{r}$, and that the proper way of writing it would be $\vec{r} = \int_{r_{a}}^{r_{b}} \mathrm{d}r_{x}\hat{\imath} + \mathrm{d}r_{y}\hat{\jmath} + \mathrm{d}r_{z}\hat{k}$. What confuses me about this is how to account for variations in the $\hat{\imath}$, $\hat{\jmath}$, and $\hat{k}$ directions. That integral makes it look like all vector components are the exact same value, and I can't wrap my head around how to account for their variation.

Comment: For some reason I am unable to edit [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987090/can-one-say-that-int-r-ar-b-mathrmd-vecr-is-the-infinite-sum-of/3987243#comment8227613_3987090) comment, so I would like to specify that instead of $\mathrm{d}r$ I meant to say all small portions of $\vec{r}$, $\mathrm{d}r$, instead of just $\mathrm{d}r$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. In physics documentation, it is very common to see vectors as a magnitude with an associated direction $r\hat r$ since having constant "track" over the direction of where the calculation is taking place is useful at times.

Comment: I think that "yes, you can" means that you can write $\vec r = r\,\hat r$, which is certainly true, but you cannot always write $\vec r(b) - \vec r(a) = \int_a^b \hat r\,\mathrm dr$ (which is what I assume was meant rather than $\int_{r_a}^{r_b} \hat r\,\mathrm dr$, which doesn't make sense to me).  Indeed, if $\vec r$ has constant length, then $\mathrm dr = 0$; but $\vec r(a)$ need not equal $\vec r(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\mathrm d\vec r = \hat r\,\mathrm dr + r\,\mathrm d\hat r$, as you would expect from the product rule.  It doesn't make sense for the limits of integration of $r$ to depend on $r$, but we can say that $\vec r(b) - \vec r(a) = \int_a^b \hat r\,\mathrm dr + \int_a^b r\,\mathrm d\hat r$, because the chain rule shows that, since $\hat r = \frac1 r\vec r$, we have $\mathrm d\hat r = \frac1 r\mathrm d\vec r - \frac1 r\hat r\,\mathrm dr$.

You already [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987090/can-one-say-that-int-r-ar-b-mathrmd-vecr-is-the-infinite-sum-of/3987243#comment8227613_3987090) that the formula $\mathrm d\vec r = \hat r\,\mathrm dr$ works in a special case; you said “all portions of $\mathrm dr$ are pointing in the direction of $\vec r$”, which doesn't directly make sense to me ($\mathrm dr$ is scalar, so doesn't have ‘portions’ in an obvious sense), but perhaps you meant “if $\mathrm d\vec r$ is always parallel to $\vec r$”.  We describe this by saying that all the acceleration of $\vec r$ is tangential.  In this case $\hat r$ is constant, so $r\,\mathrm d\hat r$ is $0$, and we recover your formula.

At the opposite extreme, if $\vec r$ has constant length $r$ (i.e., it moves around a circle centred at the origin), then $\mathrm dr$ is $0$.  We describe this situation by saying that the acceleration of $\vec r$ is normal, and we have the formula $\vec r(b) - \vec r(a) = \int_a^b r\,\mathrm d\vec r$.

In general, the acceleration of $\vec r$ has some tangential component and some normal component.  You have basically discovered the 2D part of the [Frenet–Serret frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas)!  Congratulations!

Comment: In regards to your one comment about me stating "all portions of $\mathrm{d}r$ are pointing in the direction of $\vec{r}$", I have stated an edit underneath. I wasn't able to directly edit the text for some reason.

Comment: I am quite confused about what the logical explanation of $\mathrm{d}\hat{r}$ would be. The unit vector just represents a direction of a vector on the Cartesian Plane, so what would it mean to have infinitesimally small portions of the unit vector as stated by the differential?

Comment: Again in regards to my comment that you mentioned, it's not clear to me how one would account for variations in $\hat{\imath}$, $\hat{\jmath}$, and $\hat{k}$. If you were to geometrically represent all three of those integrals, you would end up with a dimensionless $y$ axis, and a $x$ axis which represents the magnitude of the vector component. These integrals have an $f(x)$ of constant $1$, so how do you account for the variation in those unit vectors, if you were summing up a whole bunch of different $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$, which,  through the integral, sum up to $\vec{r}$?

Comment: You can only edit comments for 5 minutes.  It is not $\vec r\,\mathrm dr$, but $\mathrm d\vec r$, that you want pointing in the direction of $\vec r$ to have only tangential acceleration.  $\mathrm d\hat r$ represents an infinitesimal change in the direction (unit) vector; it is not, itself, a unit vector.  (Think $\langle\cos(\theta + \Delta\theta), \sin(\theta + \Delta\theta)\rangle - \langle\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)\rangle$.)  $\hat i$, $\hat j$, and $\hat k$ are not themselves varying; they are constant, and their components in [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8228057)

Comment: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8228054)  $\hat r$ are varying.  If you *want* a varying coördinate system, then that's what the Frenet–Serret frame is!  Here, the tangent vector is just $\hat r$, and the normal vector is just the derivative of the tangent vector, *normalised to have unit length*.  This formalises what I think is your intuition.

Comment: For a loose analogy to what it means to have $\mathrm d\hat r$, which is not a unit vector, when $\hat r$ is constrained to be a unit vector, imagine an always-positive scalar function $y$.  It makes perfect sense to speak of $\mathrm dy$ as an infinitesimal change in $y$, *even though* $y$ might is constrained to be positive *and yet* $\mathrm dy$ might be negative (if $y$ is positive but decreasing).  For example, think of $y = e^{-x}$, so $\mathrm dy = e^{-(x + \Delta x)} - e^{-x} < 0$ (if you are OK with ordering infinitesimals).